# Why use __FILE__ in Wordpress hooks?

Tags: php

I am looking at the code of a Wordpress plugin to see how they are creating and adding the database table upon activation of the plugin.

```
    // Activation hook for creating the initial DB table
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_db_table');
```

`add_db_table` is a function that creates a table, I understand that and how to create that function, but the purpose of `register_activation_hook` is to add it when the plugin is activated. I am just really curious to know why they use `__FILE__`?

I just want to fully understand, thanks!

Comment: Almost all API's have documentation to read. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Comment: yeah i 1+ you're right I didnt think it was part of wordpress default syntax, didnt think to look that up.. "Path to the main plugin file inside the wp-content/plugins directory. A full path will work." So how does `__FILE__` know the path, is it "A full path"?

Comment: FYI I was reading this http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/30/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/ and the function doesn't say there are any parameters.. so I assumed it was just bare like the tut I was reading. No reason to hop to the codex when the tut was slightly misleading making the function look bare, so I was generally curious to know why the dev passed `__FILE__` into the function.

Comment: Read PHP's API. __FILE__ is a global constant. It will explain how it knows the directory path. http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Thanks for the link, but again don't you think I tried to do some minor research before asking? I came across this http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php which was misleading to me your above link clears it up. I was just slightly misinformend in my research, so I came here to be pointed in the right direction, still don't see a need for a -1..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37212/discussion-between-rottingham-and-michael-joseph-aubry)

Comment: Thanks guys though.. I understand now.. Whenever reading a tutorial I am going to go straight to the codex to understand more about the function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

```
register_activation_hook [ WordPress Functions ]
register_activation_hook ( $file, $function ) 

Parameters: 
    (string) $file The filename of the plugin including the path.
    (callback) $function the function hooked to the 'activate_PLUGIN' action.
```

Why does WordPress function use filename as parameter :

```
function register_activation_hook($file, $function) {
    $file = plugin_basename($file);
    add_action('activate_' . $file, $function);
}
```

Comment: At least I can show some love.. thanks for the answer and the effort..